# Delete the object in place from an array: JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am having an array of objects with the following structure:

```
const timeOptions = [
  { key: "all", value: "all", text: "All" },
  { key: "month", value: "month", text: "Month" },
  { key: "year", value: "year", text: "Year" }
];
```

I am creating a new object with this timeOptions being a value of a field in it. How to remove the object with key "all" `in-place` while creating the object itself

```
const values = {
  timeVal: {
    field: "timestamp",
    label: "Timestamp",
    options: timeOptions
  }
};
```

Code that I tried

```
const values = {
  timeVal: {
    field: "timestamp",
    label: "Timestamp",
    options: timeOptions.forEach((k) => delete k["key"] === "all")
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
options: timeOptions.filter(({ key }) => key !== 'all')
```

Comment: This is an obvious and often-repeated duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need **filter**

```
const values = {
 timeVal: {
 field: "timestamp",
 label: "Timestamp",
 options: timeOptions.filter((k) =>  k["key"] !== "all")
}
```

};

This will copy all except the one with key "all"

Comment: This is an obvious and often-repeated duplicate.